# Customize Graph on Python Matplotlib

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib

I need to have a graph coded from a python data frame which shows the summary of statistics (mean, max and min) as shown. The graph desired will be like a boxplot, but without the whiskers (No 1st and 3rd quartile). Only minimum, maximum and mean time are given. The time interval and time window can be set to any and I already have the code to set the time interval and time window. Hence, I would only need a code for the graph. As there are many IDs as shown in the data frame, I would like to be able to choose which ID I want to see with a click or I can select which ID to be displayed among the list of ID available. The layout of the graph I want is shown below.

The time interval, time window and IDs can be different at any time, hence the code need to take this into consideration.

Dataframe is shown below. The time shown in the time_window eg: 2018-09-26 11:30:00 is the start of the time window. For this case, each time window is 1 minute. Hence, 2018-09-26 11:30:00 refers to 2018-09-26 11:30:00 to 11:31:00 time window. Appreciate anyone's help, thank you! I have written the code below but it is not displaying what I would want.

```
df.boxplot(column=df['mean_time (s)'], by=df['time_window'], labels=df['ID'])
plt.title('Duration of Reaction')
plt.ylabel('Duration')
plt.xlabel('Time Window')
plt.legend(df['ID'], loc='best')
plt.xticks(df['time_window'], fontsize=5)
plt.show()
```

Image of dataframe 
[image: Image of dataframe]
Image of how graph should look like: [image: Desired result]